# Como poner dato de tabla en variable php

Tags: php, mysql

Bueno, les cuento, quiero poner una ruta de una carpeta donde se guardan las imagenes que subo en mysql.
Pero el problema es que no se como ponerlo. Esto es lo que hice:

`$nuevo_path="images/".$name;`

Ya está conectado a la base, pero donde está images/ quiero que este la ruta que la edito desde la tabla.
Espero explicarme.

PD: La tabla esta estructurada así:

`id|carpeta1`
`0 |imagenes/prueba/`

Comment: no se te entiende mucho, cual es el erro ?

Comment: No es un error, leiste la pregunta? Quiero poner la estructura de la tabla de la base de datos en donde dice "**images**"

Comment: No se entiende mucho, el imagenes/prueba de  donde sale del resultado de una consulta a la base de datos ?
Es decir algo como un SELECT * FROM tabla ?

Comment: Tendras que explicarte mejor y poner mas codigo. Yo tampoco entiendo nada la verdad. Quieres `$nuevo_path= 'imagenes/prueba/'.$name;` ??

Comment: Si, pero el directorio quiero cambiarlo de la base de datos, no del codigo, y ya la tengo conectada, solo quiero saber como pongo para que tome la tabla con el id 0 y con el nombre de columna "carpeta1"